# How can hide the icon legend

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have to add a image in the legend and I wanna hide the default icon. My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2168/

```
legend: {
    useHTML:true,
    symbolWidth:0,
    labelFormatter: function() {
        return '<span class="legenditem">'+this.name +'<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Check-icon.png" width="15" height="15"></span>';
    }
},
```

Comment: which image you want to hide?

Comment: I wanna hide the colors of the legend. I only wanna stay the tick symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `symbolWidth` to `0`, and they will not be showing.

```
legend: {
    symbolWidth: 0
}
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2169/) demonstration.